# Precompression, GWT, and Tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

I'm Using tomcat 6 and 7. I'm trying to make a filter that will look for "resourceName" + .gz, and then forward the request to that resource if it exists (and the browser supports gzip).

I've tried this

```
httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(newUri).forward(httpServletRequest, response);
```

However, that does not work. The issue is that once the forward is executed, the response is committed with a content-type of application/x-gzip.  The content-type SHOULD just be whatever the content type is without the .gz extension.

I've tried adding mime-types to the web.xml file, but that does not seem to work

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>
    <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js.gz</extension>
    <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to download a gz file ?

Comment: Sort of.  For example, I'll have a javascript file that has also been gzipped. If their browser supports it, I want to redirect requests for the javascript files to the gzipped javascript files.

Comment: Can you add some more clarity to your question? Did the first answer put you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Gzip for static resources are set up by configuration in tomcat server.xml as provided in the following blog http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/

Sample server.xml snippet from a project -

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" acceptCount="100"
        connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
        enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" compression="on"
        compressionMinSize="2048"
        compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css" />
```